# Check angular 2 version and got this error

Tags: angular, command-line

After I gave the command `ng -v` I got this as the answer. Can someone please explain what is wrong here? Any issue of angular installation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you install angular cli as

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

-g makes it install globally and then you can run your command.

```
ng -v
```

or you can update the @angular/cli in your package.json in devDependencies json

from

```
"angular-cli": "anything"
```

to

```
"@angular/cli": "1.3.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` in DEMO directory does not have `angular@cli` listed in dev dependencies:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.3.0", // <--- Here is the local project package.
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.8.2"
  }
...
```

You should have local and global `@angular/cli` packages installed.

Install package using `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` and `npm install  @angular/cli@latest --save-dev`

By the way, when you install `angular/@cli` and uses `ng new` command it automatically downloads all the dependencies including `@angular/cli` for you project.